# Azure DevOps - can't find Azure Artifacts Settings - unable to remove inheritance

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I screwed up my Feed settings trying to do cross-project pushes. I think I know how to fix it, but I can't seem to get to a setting that I had changed in order to change it back. Long story short, I have inherited permissions that are blocking me, but I can't get to the screen to un-set it: 
[image]

Now these are set in a right side slide-out that has the option:

Only administrators and these users can create feeds

Which I believe is in Azure Artifacts settings according to all the documentation, but for the life of me I can't seem to find it again. Maybe I am just being dumb, but someone please help me un-set this! Thank you.

UPDATE:
I can get to the artifact and I see this: 
[image]

I checked and even made sure I have rights over everything:
[image]

But nowhere do I see "Azure Artifacts settings" so I can get rid of this inheritance - what am I missing?

Comment: The info below is what I am looking for, but I can't seem to find out how to get to the 'Azure Artifacts Settings' - wherever it was before, its either well hidden, or gone for me now?

Answer (score 2):

> Azure DevOps - can't find Azure Artifacts Settings - unable to remove inheritance

**The solution** is that searching the `User/Group` with `Inherited` in the option `Only administrators and these users can create feeds` of Azure Artifacts settings, then **remove** it:

[image]

After saving, we could delete the Project Collection Valid Users group now.

**Reproduce steps:**

1. Add the `Project Collection Valid Users group` as `Reader` on the Feed settings.
2. Add above group in the option `Only administrators and these users can create feeds` of Azure Artifacts settings.

Now, the group `Project Collection Valid Users group` marked as `Inherited` and we could not remove it:

[image]

**Solution:**

Searching the `User/Group` with `Inherited` in the option `Only administrators and remove it, then we could delete that group in the feed setting:

[image]

**Update:**

> The info below is what I am looking for, but I can't seem to find out
>   how to get to the 'Azure Artifacts Settings' - wherever it was before,
>   its either well hidden, or gone for me now?

You should check if you are an administrator for the artifact, if not, you will not see that option. As solution, you can add your account as administrator for the artifact by the administrator account.

Without administrator for the artifact, Azure Artifacts Settings missing:

[image]

Add it by Admin account:

[image]

Then, we could see that settings:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for - except I can't find the "Azure Artifacts Settings" - where do I get to that first screen?  I have seen it before (that's how I set it) but I can't seem to get back to it.  Where is "Azure Artifacts settings"???

Comment: @naspinski, I have updated my answer for your comment, please check if helps you.

Comment: @naspinski, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: updated again, still can't find the hidden settings